# hibernate wrong return type after select

Tags: hibernate, types

I have small problem with the return type of hibernate. I have the following class

```
public class Account {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="account",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Transaction> transactions;

    ...
}
```

In my first attempt I just did `createQuery("from Account").getResultList()` and it returned a List which was of type `Account` but then I wanted did this `createQuery("select id, name, date from Account")`, and I didn't got an Account objects back with `transactions` empty, I got an `Object` which don't want to be cast to Account. Any idea how I get a Account object back? A typedQuery `createQuery("from Account",Account.class")` doesn't work I either.

Comment: i believe having both Transient and OneToMany annotations will not work.  Transient means it will not be persisted to the database while OneToMany implies that this is a persisted data and has a one-to-many relationship with another entity.

Answer (score 0):

Write simple query session.createQuery("From Account").list()

Just simple add only three fields in your Account class (id, name, date). Hibernate will fill those values.
Just map the class name and column name properly by annotations.

Comment: but what if i want the Transactions in there for...stuff... but only in the rest call i want the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating fields in query gives you a list of Object arrays as a result. I.e. when you call `createQuery("select id, name, date from Account").list()` you'll get a result of type `List<Object[]>`. Each element of object array contains a value of corresponding field declared in query.

To get an Account instances for such query you may use `query.setResultTransformer(...)`. Such ResultTransformer should be implemented to build an Account instance from Object array. But I would not recommend such approach, as Account instances constructed in such way will not be under Hibernate control: changes to its fields would not be automatically flushed to database.

Instead you may declare `transactions` mapping as FetchType.LAZY and use `.createQuery("From Account").list()`. In this case `transactions` collection will not be initialized until you access it.